# Scala: How to write my own mutable array?

Tags: scala, immutability

I know there is `scala.collection.mutable` package which provides mutable data structures. But how is it done?

Can I write my own mutable data structure and pass it to a function to be changed?

Edit: The question aims towards techniques that can be used to implement mutable data types.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "How is it done?" Is there something unclear after reading the source code of the classes inside `scala.collection.mutable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this wonderful tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) on implementing custom collections in scala.
It should have all you need to answer the question "how it is done".

If you are just talking about *any* data structure, not a collection, then something like

```
 class Foo(var bar: String)
```

will do. But ... don't do it. While, there are rare and isolated cases, where having a mutable structure is unavoidable, chances are, you will not encounter such a case for a long time.

My advice to you is to start with learning to write good, idiomatic scala code, and getting into the functional mindset, where data structures don't mutate under you. Learn to appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can. There is no limitation, that all immutable data structures should be inside `scala.collection.immutable`, and all mutable DS should be inside `scala.collection.mutable`. Standard collection classes are divided into these two packages just for convenience. You can create your classes, where you like to do it.